# ElasticSearch Update by query max_compilations_per_minute exceded

Tags: elasticsearch

I got this request :

```
{
                "script":{
                    "inline":"ctx._source.music_tags=" + JSON.stringify(music_tags),
                    "lang":"painless"
                },
                "query":{
                    "constant_score":{
                        "filter":{
                            "term":{
                                "release_id": releaseId
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can see i'm trying to update all document with a certain releaseId.
Everything is working fine but as soon as i try to update a lot of data simultaneously i get the folowing error:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "root_cause":[  
         {  
            "type":"circuit_breaking_exception",
            "reason":"[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within one minute, max: [15/min]; please use on-disk, indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.max_compilations_per_minute] setting",
            "bytes_wanted":0,
            "bytes_limit":0
         }
      ],
      "type":"general_script_exception",
      "reason":"Failed to compile inline script [ctx._source.music_tags=[\"25319\",\"25390\",\"25795\"]] using lang [painless]",
      "caused_by":{  
         "type":"circuit_breaking_exception",
         "reason":"[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within one minute, max: [15/min]; please use on-disk, indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.max_compilations_per_minute] setting",
         "bytes_wanted":0,
         "bytes_limit":0
      }
   },
   "status":500
}
```

I did try to find any information on this limitation but i didnt quite get it.

Can someone explain why do elasticSearch have this limitation and what is the impact if i change this limit ?

Can i update my document without script ?

If i use a parameter for each request (cf: [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#prefer-params)) , will i still get the limit error ?

Thanks,

Théo

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error and later i found that there was minor syntax error in the expression. It got resolved after fixing the syntax error. Did you check if JSON is valid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the "script.max_compilations_per_minute" setting to increase the limit of script compilations.

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "script.max_compilations_per_minute": 40
  }
}
```